# Webpack - dependency not found (isotope)

Tags: webpack, dependencies, jquery-isotope, laravel-mix

I am using Webpack (the laravel mix version) and get an error with Isotope.   Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

**This dependency was not found:* masonry/masonry in ./~/isotope-layout/js/layout-modes/masonry.js**

This is my webpack confix, I ahve tried to apply the 'fix' as shown on the isotope site

```
const webpack = require('webpack')
const path    = require('path')

const config = {
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'masonry': 'masonry-layout',
      'isotope': 'isotope-layout'
    }
  },
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    filename: 'vue-waypoint.js',
    library: 'VueWaypoint',
    libraryTarget: 'umd'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, './src'),
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: "babel-loader"
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin(),
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({ minimize: true })
  ]
}

module.exports = config;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is very strange, looks like you try to rename npm packages `masonry-layout` and `isotope-layout` in your code, but alias is about folders and paths (https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-alias)

You can simply use:
`require('masonry-layout')` or `import Istotope from 'masonry-layout'` when you do `npm i masonry-layout --save`

Or you can pass 'masonry-layout' as global package:

`new webpack.ProvidePlugin({masonry: 'masonry-layout'})`